# How insert with no duplicates?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert some records in my product table, I need to insert products where are no repeating model code, I use the query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO erp_product
  (erp_model, erp_ean, erp_cstid, erp_quantity,
  erp_brand_erp_brandid, erp_price, erp_cost, 
  erp_weight, erp_lenght, erp_width, erp_height,
  erp_status, erp_distributor, erp_registerdate)
VALUES(
       '020-113_24','7897712061589',1,0,
       '1','22.85','17.58',
       '0.03','13','14','5',
       0,'OP','06/07/2017 10:32:47');
```

I need use `WHERE NOT IN` or `WHERE NOT EXISTS`? What is the difference?
The insert not works, any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What primary/unique keys exist on the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to insert products where are no repeating model code

Well then why not define a `UNIQUE` constraint on `erp_model` column. like

```
ALTER TABLE erp_product ADD CONSTRAINT constr_unq UNIQUE (erp_model)
```